# Tinymce editor not saving data if there is "from" keyword in the content

Tags: codeigniter, tinymce

I am using **`tinymce editor`** as rich text editor for **`blog management system`** and **`codeigniter`** for saving data in the database.

I am trying to save the following text in the database. I am unable to save the content. I tried to debug the issue and figured out that the issue is with the word "from". If I remove "from" I am able to save it in the database.

**Here is the text:**

Negotiating a mortgage is more complicated than negotiating just a rate. Unfortunately, clients too often lose thousands of dollars because they were poorly advised. Here are **`7 questions`** that your banker should be able to answer:

1. **`What is the penalty if I want to break my mortgage and how is it calculated?`**
2. **`Is my mortgage transferable to another property? If yes, under what conditions?`**
3. **`Can I convert my mortgage to a fixed rate?`**
4. **`Is my mortgage subsidiary (blanket) or traditional?`**
5. **`What are my pre-payment options?`**
6. **`What factors influence the fluctuation of fixed rates?`**
7. **`What factors influence the fluctuation of variable rates?`**

If your banker is unable to answer all the questions above, or if you don’t understand all the implications of the answers, then maybe it’s time to consult a mortgage broker. Mortgage brokers represent several lenders and can explain the terms and conditions of the different lenders and their impact. Brokers are paid by the lenders, and the remuneration is similar from one lender to another so, unlike bankers who offer just their employer’s products, brokers have a vested interest in explaining the particulars of the various products. Sign up for our newsletter **`"Plani-Info"`** in order to not miss out on anything in our blog! Feel free to share this article with your friends, colleagues and family who might need it.

### The content of this website is protected by copyright which is the exclusive property of Mortgage Planners – Mortgage Agency.

I am not getting the above content in codeigniter method.

I tried debugging the post parameters

```
print_r($this->input->post('content'));
```

The result of above is empty string. Where "content" is the name of tinymce textarea input field.

Any idea why? Thanks for you help

Comment: Without telling us how you are attempting to store the data (and showing the code) people will only be guessing at what is causing this to happen.  Please review how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is a server configuration issue. The information is submitted through the form is triggering an SQL Injection error in the ModSecurity software on the server. In order to whitelist or avoid this trigger, the specific page needs to be added to the conf file.

Log in to the server through SSH as admin To add rules to whitelist vi /etc/apache2/conf.d/modsec2/whitelist.conf

Example:

```html
<LocationMatch "/page_url_where_you_added_tiinymce_editor/*"> 
    SecRuleRemoveById 300016 300014 
</LocationMatch>
```

Restart Apache after changes made